# BizTalk Tracking query timeout settings not used

Tags: biztalk

I have a timeout while querying the BizTalk Tracking database from the BizTalk MMC console.
I follow several posts to change Registry settings (32 and 64 bits) and the settings are not used by the console because it systematically failed after a few seconds (30 maybe) even if I set the query timeout to 120.
It is for BizTalk 2013 R2.
Any ideas?

Comment: Just to be sure: did you reopen the console? If you changed the settings under Local Machine make sure there's nothing under Current User that says something else.

Comment: Which is the size of your DTA? Are DTA Purge job running fine?

Comment: I reopen the console yes. I will check if there is something under the CurrentUser key.

The size of the database is around 2GB.

When I track the query sent by the console and play it directly with SQL Server Management Studio, it takes around 70 secs to return results.